# How does a photon know what to do when It interacts with the first surface of a LIGO mirror?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, electromagnetic-radiation, photons, reflection

There are 72 alternating boundaries (optical coatings) to traverse before it can decide whether to reflect or pass through the mirror. The boundary properties are such that the the first boundary by itself without the subsequent deeper boundaries would reflect 5 or 10 percent of photons. the achieved probability of reflection with 72 optimally designed boundaries is well in excess of 99.99 percent.
Does each photon send an agent down through the boundaries measuring and recording variables doing calculations and then returning to the hovering photon and report "you are not allowed through"until (statistically) 99.99% of you have been reflected.  all this measuring takes place in no time, the agent travels very much faster than light.    Can someone QM explain how the photon does this. It's simple for Maxwell to explain it.   The LIGO mirror is also a high Q cavity. As we all know there is significant delay in photon's traversing a high Q cavity, but in this case the photon never penetrates the cavity due to the,99.9999% reflectivity. Does the photon wait outside the mirror until such time it is due to reflect back to the source.  Does the initial group of photon's wait longer than later groups if you assume a rectangular bunch of photons in the form of a pulse from the laser, or even a step function would suffice for a gedanken experiment.

Comment: Normal glass is ~ 3.5% reflective, 7% if you include both sides .... reflection process is the same in glass as in the LIGO mirror. Photons will penetrate to various depths in the LIGO layers, once in a while one gets thru.  Its all about how the wave in the EM field reacts with the EM field of the material, and probability is also important.

Comment: You are nitpicking PhyicsDave It will be optical glass of some variety,  and I think the laser may be infrared. In short I don't know.  I'm also trying to find some points of difference between EM and "photons", so you are confusing me by flitting between EM and Photons and cherry picking their properties, probabilities seem to be red herring that is QM speak.

Comment: Yes it is special glass and IR, typical glass value of 3.5/7.5% is for vis light, IR is why the number is 5/10%. In both cases the physics is the same.  Science has invented the EM field to explain photons, they are much the same thing. Think of a photon as a wave in the EM field, like a clap/short sound in air. The wave was produced by an electron in an atom (in the laser) and it will absorb or reflect/transmit based on the material property it hits.  Each layer is 1/2 or multiple of 1/2 of the light wavelength, this is the worst case for the light to form a wave, thus reflection (and QM!).

Comment: PysicsDave   Said: "Science has invented the EM field to explain photons,",  I dispute this statement.

Comment: I also dispute that electrons absorb photons.   That statement is a factoid!      Electrons are accelerated by interaction with fields and waves!

Comment: maybe better stated as electrons in atoms/molecules absorb photons!  Maybe scientists have discovered the EM field?

Comment: PhysicsDave  Why do you erroneously insist that electrons absorb photons? I say again they are accelerated by photons. Maxwell discovered EM long before photons were proposed.

Comment: PhysicsDave  said:"The wave was produced by an electron in an atom (in the laser) and it will absorb or reflect/transmit based on the material property it hits. Each layer is 1/2 or multiple of 1/2 of the light wavelength, this is the worst case for the light to form a wave, thus reflection (and QM!)." The question is how does a "photon" know what to do, it never actually hits any of the necessary boundaries to decide what to do. Only the classical wave can do this, because it can be divided and send its little waves all over the boundaries back and fourth and form a vector sum.

Comment: It sounds like you are asking how an apple knows how to drop .... it's all due to forces and fields, there is no "knowing" required.  Indeed the photon interacts with each boundary one after the other in succession, i.e. ones that bounce off the first layer will return sooner to the detector than ones that may end up bouncing off the 50th layer.  Yes you can solve it all with Maxwelll equations, they will predict what % are reflected/transmitted.

Comment: PhysicsDave  There is a misunderstanding of the question on your part.   The mirror is almost 100% reflective for the complete mirror, but each  layer is only about  10%, does the photon instantly reflect off the first boundary with almost 100% probability? the probability of the photon passing through the mirror is almost zero. Remember the photon must retains its integrity. The plane wave divides at each boundary. The vector sum of all wave fragments sum to 0 after two propagation delays of the mirror.

Comment: The vector sum theory is a classical one and while it works mathematically (and is taught in 1st /2nd year uni) it does violate conservation of energy.  Quantum optics (4th year?) resolves/explains what is observed when single photons are also observed to "interfere". Your question gets right at the heart of the same issue, how could a photon know ... the answer is it can't, thus quantum optics.  2 photons do not interfere in QO. See my answer here. https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/634135/why-does-em-destructive-interference-reflect-on-an-resonnant-cavity-chamber-but/634231#634231

Comment: In order to answer your question with QO it is necessary to look at the quanta level ( I won't use the word photon).  The wave you mention is made of many quanta or many localized/smallish energy packets with wave properties. Each quanta interacts independently of each other when meeting matter.  A narrow pulse of light will spread out in time in the LIGO mirror and come back to the detector as a wider pulse in time. This is a results of some quanta reflected at the first layer and others at the various depths.

Comment: I'm not aware of this, could you please expand? " it does violate conservation of energy. Quantum optics (4th year?) "

Comment: No doubt Compton scattering will be raised? This is easy for Maxwell!

Comment: barry you: « Electrons are accelerated by interaction with fields and waves!«   Me: a different point of view http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/90646/what-is-the-relation-between-electromagnetic-wave-and-photon/253957#253957

Answer (score 1):

It works like this. You solve Maxwells equations. Then the potential tells you how many photons you can expect on average, that is, it gives you the average of a Poisson or Gauss distribution. This distribution is the  experimental prediction. We only know how it works not why it works like this.

Comment: Not sure why this got a -1 but I think this is a correct answer (+1).

Comment: my2cts said: "It works like this. You solve Maxwell's equations. Then the potential tells you how many photons you can expect on average, that is, it gives you the average of a Poisson or Gauss distribution. This distribution is the experimental prediction. We only know how it works not why it works like this."   Are you saying only Maxwell is required? why use "photons" at all?

Comment: The comnent section is not for extended discussion. For new questions you should submit a separate post.

Answer (score -6):

Yes, you solve Maxwell's equation's and that is the end of the matter. Photons will not contribute anything to the solution.  Not only do photons complicate things but lead to paradox's and faster than light influences.
Maxwell solution's remove the paradox's in most of QM.   Young's two slit experiment at low intensity (G. I. Taylor's experiment), or two slit interference as it is now days referred to. The Nobel laureate Willis Lamb Jr. Insisted that the photon is unnecessary in this link:   https://jumpshare.com/v/cxGki8ocqtHqajtpknCA

According to Niels Bohr’s “correspondence principle” the raison d’etre for QM was to explain the microscopic world and its attendant uncertain statistical nature, which must asymptote to equal classical interpretation for large ensembles of particles.  Many comments on the LIGO mirror seem to interpret the “correspondence principle” in reverse. “First ,you solve Maxwell’s equations, and then, Blah, Blah and Blah”.   I must be missing something?

Comment: Hm. I agree you can get the correct answer with Maxwell's equations but I don't agree at all that "Maxwell solution's remove the paradox's in most of QM". Maxwell's equations are just an *approximation* to quantum mechanics and ultimately we need to be able to explain any phenomenon involving light in terms of photons. Photons are absolutely necessary for describing physical reality, for example consider blackbody radiation, the photoelectric effect, and Compton scattering.

Comment: Willis didn't like the confusion that the particle view caused, in any sentence that uses the  word photon you can just substitute the words "EM wave" and you will make Willis happy.  It's fine. Most important is that there is an EM field everywhere for the EM waves.  An EM wave interacts with EM field in any material, the material field being primarily from the electrons ... this interaction is not 100% predictable ( as Einstein would have hoped) instead the best way to estimate or quantify it is with probabilities (or as the Phds like to say QM).

Comment: An example of EM not being 100% predictable if you can, no sophistry please.

Comment: The Nobel laureate Max Planck did not like the photon.

Comment: You can google " quantum random number generator" and get many examples.

Comment: I don't understand your  "quantum random number generator", or "examples" of what?

Comment: When a plane wave impinges on a polished aluminium sheet (light sail),The reflected wave is now slightly Doppler shifted to a longer wavelength (lower frequency) because of the translation of the sail. Also energy conservation demands that the scattered wave must be of lower energy (frequency) because the sail has gained momentum. This mechanism explains the principle at work in Compton scattering.

Comment: Planck was awarded a Nobel prize for his work on the discrete nature of radiation from matter (black body radiation) but he did not believe that the radiated field was discrete. black body radiation does not demand that the radiated field be discrete.

Comment: I can solve the Maxwell's equation's and get the EXACT answer.  RF engineers and opticians do this routinely.

Comment: The photoelectric effect and Compton scattering are a doddle for Maxwell. Blackbody radiation is not explained by QM Planck plugged numbers in by hand until he got the correct curve. Prof. timothy Boyer has derived Planck's constant analytically and classically.