# Why does EM destructive interference reflect on an resonnant cavity chamber but not on a piece of paper?

Tags: electromagnetism, reflection, resonance

Case 1) Light passing through a single or double slit with show an interference pattern on a screen with dark fringes. The observer eye wont receive light comming from the dark fringes (and therefore perceive them as dark) and therefore we can assume that no light is emitted or reflected from the dark fringes.

Case 2) Resonnant EM cavity, the EM potential at the wall of the cavity is 0 (similar to a dark fringe), but we know that light is reflected otherwise the cavity (laser or microwave oven) wouldnt resonate.

Why is it that, in case 1, a 0 EM potential (be it electric or magnetic) doesnt emit/reflect light but does so in case 2 ?

Answer (score 1):

I think we can understand this in the following simple terms:
Case 1 the double slit experiment:  The electric field at the wall $E_w$ is zero because of the contributions of two sources (the two slits) $S_1$, and $S_2$, $E_w = S_1 + S_2 = 0$. Note that here both $S_1$ and $S_2$ are propagating *towards* the wall, and thus an observer looking at the wall will have neither $S_1$ or $S_2$ propagating towards him. Thus he sees this portion of the wall as dark.

Case 2 EM cavity: Allow me to make the simplification to just a single source pointing at a metallic wall. It's the same problem really, we see a reflection (a shiny wall) even though $E_w = 0$. The reason for this is that $E_w$ here is the contribution of $S$ the source and $R$ the reflected wave. Thus we can write $E_w = S+R = 0$. But now $S$ and $R$ are propagating in opposite directions, in particular an observer looking at the wall has $R$ propagating towards him.

You might want to think of $R$ as being generated by the response of material to the sources. So in case 1 the wall has no response at all since the two sources cancel, (the wall *feels* no fields to responded to). However in case 2, the wall *feels* $S$, responds by $R$ (such that $E_w = 0$), and you observe this response.

Comment: Would you say Ew=0 because of the reflected wave cancelling the incoming, or rather because the wall is conducting (and possibly grounded) ?

Comment: @ManudeHanoi The general boundary condition as derived form Maxwell's equations for an uncharged surface is that the electric field is continuous, i.e. the fields just inside the material is equal to the field just outside the material. In a conductor, there are no transmitted waves (strictly speaking the field dies exponentially inside a conductor, the characteristic length is called the penetration depth). In general, the fields outside are $S$ and $R$ and the fields inside are $T$ (transmitted), and the boundary condition is $S+R = T$. Since for a conductor $T = 0$, we have $S+R = 0$.

Comment: In your case 1 what becomes of the energy of the photons at the dark areas on the wall?

Comment: @PhysicsDave The magnitude of the electric field doesn't change the energy of photons (this would be dictated by the frequency), rather it change the number of photons. In this sense because $S_1+ S_2 = 0$ there are no photons at all at the regions of the wall where there are destructive interference.

Comment: If there are no photons in the dark bands then how can there be destructive interference there?

Comment: @PhysicsDave Well, the way we think of destructive interference is not in terms of two photons colliding and destroying each other. In terms of photons, you will want to think about probability amplitudes, the square of which gives the probability of finding a photon. The amplitudes can constructively or destructively interfere. In the latter case, we get no probability of finding a photon. Sorry I can't explain a lot of quantum mechanics in one comment.

Comment: Sorry to be a pain but probability amplitudes are always positive, aren't they? .... so they can never be destructive.

Comment: No, probability amplitudes are complex numbers. The modulus square of a probability amplitude gives the probability, which is positive.

Comment: OK I agree with that. But the point I'm trying to make is we have probability amplitude for electrons in atoms with the Schrodinger / Maxwell equation which do represent physical forces of E and M which we know are present ( as the electron moves it generates these forces).  But we do not have any such "wave function" for the photon ( I don't count the Maxwell plane wave, it's not a probability function). So we know of no forces that make the photon go here or there.   The only forces that could/would explain this are possibly the ones due to the virtual photons.

Comment: @PhysicsDave You seem to be struggling with your photons and mysterious forces, come over to the Maxwell team, plane waves interfering and stuff, it's easier and we even do Compton scattering, black body and photoelectric effect  now.

Comment: @barry Yes virtual photons are required for all static EM forces, are they mysterious? .... I guess so but no more so than gravity or photons or the other 5 fundamental forces from the standard model. P.S. did you ever get any satisfaction on your LIGO mirror question?

Comment: @PhysicsDave.....I have missed your point about "virtual photons" The Maxwell team never feel the need for virtual stuff. mysticism, or faster than light influences...........       No the LIGO mirror question is still not satisfactorily answered. I could answer it myself, or offer a bounty, what would you advise on this?

Comment: @PhysicsDave....You need forces to guide your "particles", us Maxwellian's use wave interference, energy cancellation in the dark bands appears in the bright bands. This wave phenomena is identical in sound, water and strings, no mysticism just "mainstream" wave theory.

Comment: @barry An excited electron can give out virtual forces for even milliseconds before a photon is emitted, an excited electron is an unstable beast. Virtual forces (virtual photons - see the standard model in wikipedia) act at the speed of light as well a the regular photons ... no need for faster than light mysteries.

Comment: @barry yes classically I could state that it is the virtual forces that are interfering and then we would be closer in agreement. I think there is more mystery in saying that the energy goes from dark to bright ... how does that happen exactly!!?

Comment: @barry wrt to the LIGO question:  Quantum optics is where you need to go to get a better theory.  You want to lump all the photons together and say we have one big wave which is more classical and then solve Maxwell or you can say the lumped wave is still able to be broken down into its individual quanta with each quanta acting in accordance with the Maxwell equations but in a probabilistic fashion.

Comment: @PhysicDave....In reply to comment re:"virtual photons"....Modern EM does not have virtual stuff, but from what I gleaned from Wiki and other sources relating to virtual photons, it could be explained classically by using near field analysis. The humble transformer operates in an extreme region of the near field, often referred to as the induction field. Nothing would be gained by introducing virtual photons into any analysis of near field devices....

Comment: ... Nevertheless the transformer is not without some “mysticism”.  The secondary winding of a transformer can develop an emf in the absence of any B field, however there is a healthy A field in the area of the secondary winding?!  You see QM does not have a total monopoly on mysticism and witchcraft.

Comment: @PhysicsDave...Regarding the LIGO mirror, I will add some material to that question to make it even more difficult for QM to explain.

Comment: @PhysicsDave....According to Niels Bohr’s “correspondence principle” the raison d’etre for QM was to explain the microscopic world and its attendant uncertain statistical nature, which must asymptote to equal classical interpretation for large ensembles of particles.  Many comments on the LIGO mirror seem to interpret the “correspondence principle” in reverse. “First, you solve Maxwell’s equations, and then, Blah, Blah and Blah”.   I must be missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Case(1) The interference pattern on the paper destroys the coherent phase information and scatters the light. If a polished mirror was used as the screen, various interference results would be observed as "speckle".
Case(2) The microwave oven is not usually resonant but the six walls are seen as polished mirrors (specular) to radio frequency waves.   There are two distinctly different types of  waves discussed in EM theory, standing waves and traveling waves. One form of standing wave results from the vector sum (interference) of a traveling wave reflecting off a mirror interfering with the traveling wave impinging on the mirror (speckle). Inside your microwave oven is lot of standing waves. the nature of the waves at the boundary of one of the walls is that ***the E field sums to zero at a conducting boundary but the B field sums constructively at the same boundary***, the energy contained in the E field is converted to magnetic energy in the B field. this conversion continues back and forth along the standing wave, If you could observe these fields you would observe RF speckle.  Speckle is light and dark spots that move about as you the observer moves about in a sea of standing waves.  Observe supermarket scanners for speckle, if you move the speckle moves.  Fading of radio signals when driving slowly is another example. Standing waves are not dissipative but are reactive. but when you  put a chicken in the microwave. dielectric losses attenuate the waves changing the phase of the waves, the E and B come into phase indicating energy absorption is occurring (energy converted to power), the chicken tends towards a black body radiator at this point.  Somewhat remarkably,the peak of the approximate black body spectrum will be at a very much higher frequency than the initial microwave frequency, Many tens of thousands of GHz.

Comment: E going to zero does not mean energy went to zero. the current induced into the boundary generates magnetic energy.

Answer (score 0):

In the DSE from single photon experiments we know there are no photons in the dark bands, all the photons are in the bright bands.  An explanation for this is provided by considering the Feynman path integral theory, which basically states that a photon predetermines its path by considering all paths, the highest probability path that results is one that is the shortest as well as being an integer multiple of the light wavelength.  This mathematical theory produces the same result as the classical interference based theory, however it does not violate conservation of energy.

In a laser cavity we have the lasing medium which continually converts electrical energy to light. It requires that one of the mirrors be leaky otherwise there is no energy conversion in the medium. A way to think of this is that the leak allows photons to have acceptable paths where they can be absorbed by atoms/molecules.

We never know or can measure emitted light unless it is absorbed somewhere like in our detector.  Taking this further we can say light is never emitted until it has a known path to be absorbed.  Conceptually no field and zero field are different situations, we can have superimposed zero value EM fields in space but never observe them.  We only observe the full EM value when it is absorbed.